# Big O and running time of specific method given $\Theta(n)$ information on inner function

Tags: asymptotics

If evaluating $f(n)$ is $\Theta(n)$

```
i = 1;
sum = 0;
while (i <= n)
       do if (f(i) > k)
            then sum += f(i);
          i = 2*i;
```

Would the running time of this be $O(nlogn)$ because i is doubled after each iteration and the function is called the same number of times? Or could it even be a linear case?  I am very lost on this...

Comment: Your indendation is a little off. If $f(i) \leq k$, is $i = 2i$ still executed?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am assuming it is done in the while loop. The question was posed as if it were lined up with the if though.

Answer (score 1):

The worst case is if $f(i) \gt k$ is always true, so you can delete that from the code except that you compute $f(i)$ twice per loop.  You are correct that you do $\log_2 n$ passes through the loop, so you do $2 \log_2 n$ evaluations of $f$.  The final result is $f(1)+f(2)+f(4)+f(8)+\ldots f(2^k)$ for $k$ the smallest value where $2^k \gt n$  The sum of the arguments is about $2^{k+1} \approx 2n$ and the total time is about $4n$.  The point is that the early passes are called with small values of the argument, so presumably they run faster than $\Theta(n)$